# (Re)mount all network drives from fstab

Tags: mount, nfs, cifs

From Gentoo, I remember a separate `/etc/init.d` entry for mounting network drives (i.e., separate from local drives).  In Ubuntu, there is `umountnfs.sh`, which is used during shutdown (in order to ensure clean unmounting while the network is still available), and which one can use to *unmount* all (currently mounted) network drives.

However, I am missing a quick way for

- mounting all network drives from `/etc/fstab` that are not up yet, and/or
- remounting all network drives (e.g., if the credentials / rights of cifs mounts have been changed).

I would prefer a maintained 3rd party solution over a one-line shell hack.

Comment: Define "one-line shell hack". Would that include `mount -a -O cifs` for example?

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed a good answer.  I just found out that the `-t` option to `mount` can be used in conjunction with `-a`, such that `sudo mount -a -t cifs` does what I need.

Comment: Actually, `-O` is probably better. Hang on, writing it up now.

Comment: How should I proceed with this question?  While you were giving the answer in your comment, I was wondering whether I should answer myself?  Should you give an official "answer" that I can accept?  Should I delete the question?

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer. That is both allowed and encouraged on the stack exchange network. I have also posted mine but that does not mean you should feel pressured to accept it if it's not the approach you prefer. You are, of course, welcome to accept it if that's what you want  ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're looking for the `-t` flag for `mount`. From `man mount`:

```
   -t, --types vfstype
   [...]

   More than one type may be specified in a comma  separated  list.
   The  list of filesystem types can be prefixed with no to specify
   the filesystem types on which no action should be taken.   (This
   can be meaningful with the -a option.) For example, the command:

            mount -a -t nomsdos,ext
```

So, this command would mount all `cifs` filesystems:

```
sudo mount -a -t cifs
```

Comment: I don't understand why `-O` should be better in general, since it depends on some *option* to be set in the network filesystems.  In fact, it does not work for me (while `-t` does), since it does not match the fstype column.

Comment: @hans_meine I stand corrected, answer edited.

Comment: It seems like every question that asks how to do something with fstab is answered with "use mount", and every question about using mount says to use fstab.  People, sometimes these questions are here for a reason. If I am mounting a network drive with fstab, it is probably because the mount command requires root, and that even if you use sudo, the mounted folders are then OWNED by root and therefore are read only by all commands that are not also executed with sudo.

Comment: @Nuzzolilo, the OP was asking for a quick, manual way of mounting all network mounts from `fstab`. Of course the answer was `mount`, what else would it be? If you have a different question, please _ask it_ instead of complaining about how the answers to somebody else's question don't answer yours. Also, there's no reason why `root` should own the mounted directories, nor why they should be read only. Have a look at the `mount` man page.

Comment: @terdon How would I know what it should be?  And since you asked, yes I have been asking my own questions, feel free to answer them if you think you can swing it.

Comment: @Nuzzolilo  My point is that _this_ question needed a `mount` answer so I don't see why you attacked me with no reason. I'd be happy to try and help if I can, and if you provide a link to your question.

Comment: It wasn't intended to be a personal attack, but perhaps I should have written about this in the meta section instead.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/users/488069/nuzzolilo?tab=questions both of those I have found workarounds for but no direct solution.  I worry that Linux troubleshooting is trending to being workaround-driven which leads to a lot of technical debt in the ecosystem.  I'll post the concerns in the meta at some point.,

Answer (score 7):

I just found out that the `-t` option to `mount` can be used in conjunction with `-a`, such that

```
sudo mount -a -t cifs
```

does what I need.  (`sudo mount -a -t cifs -o remount` works as well, for remounting after permission / password changes.)